# I have the sharpest beak in all my friends . Who am I?

Tags: riddle

My body is green
My hair and eyebrows are blue
My eyes are a very light shade of purple
I have the sharpest beak in all my friends
I painted my wall and floor in a light shade of purple
I am named after the second greatest creator

***Who am I?***

Hint #1:

> I don't have a beak!

Hint #2:

> My species is quite popular in SE.

Hint #3:

> My species vary a lot in color.

Hint #4:

> I'm a physical object, but you don't even know if I exist or not.

Hint #5:

> You might want to wander around on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). There's a post there related to the answer.

Comment: I'm tempted to answer "a typical Londoner"

Comment: @leoll2 Nope. Not at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up @randal'thor's answer I think it's

> [Jeff Atwood's unicorn avatar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns)

*I am named after the second greatest creator*

> Jeff Atwood co-founded (the precursor to) SE with Joel Spolsky. 
>  All the other hints are self-explanatory, I think.

Comment: I was thinking Jeff Atwood, but unfortunately I looked at the wrong avatar: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/51d623f33f8b83095db84ff35e15dbe8?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's

> an accepted answer on Stack Exchange.

*My body is green*

> Refers to the green checkmark on the accepted answer.

*My hair and eyebrows are blue*

> The upvote/downvote arrows turn blue when pressed.

*My eyes are a very light shade of purple*

> The background colour on a spoilertag is very slightly off-white, and could be a very pale purple.

*I have the sharpest beak in all my friends*

> A metaphorical way of saying it's the best answer.

*I painted my wall and floor in a light shade of purple*

> Spoilertags again?

*I am named after the second greatest creator*

> Not sure about this line.

All the hints fit, if

> we take "colour" in the 3rd hint to be a metaphor for type/quality of answer.

Comment: Very good guess! Sorry, that's not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Second try:

> [BoltClock's a Unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn).

Most of it is fairly self-explanatory from the picture in the link: green body, blue hair and eyebrows, very pale purple eyes, purple background. Probably

> "beak" = "horn".

I'm not sure about "named after the second greatest creator" though. As for the hints:

> if you've spent much time on Meta.SE, you'll know that unicorns are something of a meme there (e.g. see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122026/what-is-unicorn-on-stack-overflow) page). They come in many different colours and are physical objects whose existence is ... shall we say, doubted.

Comment: Yes, it is a unicorn. It isn't BoltClock's unicorn though.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the right answer due to your hints, but I'll post this anyway:

> A Christmas tree

My body is green

> Christmas trees are evergreens.

My hair and eyebrows are blue

> They could be decorated with blue tinsel.

My eyes are a very light shade of purple

> Christmas lights could be red/pink/purple.

I have the sharpest beak in all my friends

> Pine needs can be sharp.  Or the star at the top of the tree could be sharp.

I painted my wall and floor in a light shade of purple

> Purple Christmas lights would color the walls and floor purple.

I am named after the second greatest creator

> Christmas is named after (Jesus) Christ, who could be considered second to God.